# Detect file changes in node.js via watchFile

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to detect changes for a file, if the file changes, I will use child_process to execute a scp command to copy the file to a server.I looked up node.js documentation, the fs.watchFile function seems do what I want to do, but when I tried it, somehow it just doesn't work as I expected. The following code were used:

```
var fs = require('fs');                                                                        

console.log("Watching .bash_profile");

fs.watchFile('/home/test/.bash_profile', function(curr,prev) {
    console.log("current mtime: " +curr.mtime);
    console.log("previous mtime: "+prev.mtime);
    if (curr.mtime == prev.mtime) {
        console.log("mtime equal");
    } else {
        console.log("mtime not equal");
    }   
});
```

With above code, if I access the watched file, the callback function get execute, it will output the same mtime, and always output "mtime not equal" (I only accessing the file). Outputs:

```
Watching .bash_profile
current mtime: Mon Sep 27 2010 18:41:27 GMT+0100 (BST)
previous mtime: Mon Sep 27 2010 18:41:27 GMT+0100 (BST)
mtime not equal
```

Anybody know why the if statement failed(also tried using === identify check, but still get the same output) when the two mtime are the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `mtime` properties are `Date` objects, then these can never be equal. In JavaScript two separate objects are equal ONLY if they are actually the same object (variables are pointing to the same memory instance)

```
obj1 = new Date(2010,09,27);
obj2 = new Date(2010,09,27);
obj3 = obj1; // Objects are passed BY REFERENCE!

obj1 != obj2; // true, different object instances
obj1 == obj3; // true, two variable pointers are set for the same object
obj2 != obj3; // true, different object instances
```

To check if these two date values are the same, use

```
curr.mtime.getTime() == prev.mtime.getTime();
```

(I'm not actually sure if this is the case since I didn't check if `watchFile` outputs Date objects or strings but it definitely seems this way from your description)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realized that mtime property is a object(I thought they are string object:( I used typeof curr.mtime, it return object, Is there a way in javascript to find out what kind of object?. In the example you given, I thought obj1 == obj2, because you only change the equality check, its only false when they do the identify check obj1 ==== obj2.

Comment: You can use the operator `instanceof` like this: `var d = new Date(); if(d instanceof Date == true)alert(1);` or alternatively to get the textual object type use `var d = new Date(); Object.prototype.toString.call(d); // "[object Date]"`

Comment: One thing that I notices is that, if I do something like: __var i = 10; if (i instanceof Number) alert(1);__ the if statement never true(typeof i => "number" and Object.prototype.toString.call(i) => "[object Number]", however if I declare i as: var i = Number(10), it works. Anyone know the reason behind it?

Comment: `10` is not an object but literal and `new Number(10)` is a object - `instanceof` works only with objects. If you check with `typeof` then `typeof 10 == "number"` but `typeof new Number(10) == "object"`. So as `new Number(10)` is an object, the `instanceof` operator starts to work.

Answer (score 16):

For "clever" people:

```
if (curr.mtime - prev.mtime) {
    // file changed
}
```

Comment: you're probably writing pseudo, but just to clarify since these are date objects and not integer values: +curr.mtime - +prev.mtime

Comment: @DirkSmaverson subtraction coerces the date objects into numbers, just as the unary plus operator does, so it is equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

Sadly the correct way is

```
if (+curr.mtime === +prev.mtime) {}
```

The + forces the Date object to int which is unixtime.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things you can use [Watchr](https://github.com/bevry/watchr) to get useful events (will only fire the `change` event if a file has actually changed). It also supports watching entire directory trees :)

Answer (score 1):

We use chokidar for file watching, which works even in the dubious context of a centos machine running with a windows file system (vagrant virtualbox centos running on windows machine)

https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

Comment: This is working for me, monitoring when files are updated on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

quick and nasty solution.
If you are not doing a date comparison in terms of previous or after (< or >) and you are simply comparing the datestrings, just do a quick toString() on each one.

```
 if (curr.mtime.toString() == prev.mtime.toString())
```